# Double Integral in R with 2 variables

Tags: r, integral

I'm sorry. But I'm still confused how I can get my question from those answers. My question is following.

I would like to code this calculation in R:

[image]

From my hand, it becomes 141,66666666 π. I know how to take a integral if both integrals are from exact numbers using adaptIntegrate(). But I'm not sure how to do in my case. Could you guys help me? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far

Comment: A standard way of proceeding is to estimate integrals using Monte Carlo simulations (if a large number of simulations you can have a rather precise estimates). If you transform your problem into a random variable problem, you can have an estimates for your double integral

Answer (score 1):

With `pracma::integral2`:

```
library(pracma)

fun <- function(x,y) sqrt(2.5^2 * (1 - x^2/5^2 - y^2/8.5^2))
xmin <- 0; xmax <- 5
ymin <- 0; ymax <- function(x) sqrt(8.5^2 * (1-x^2/5^2))

integral2(fun, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# $Q
# [1] 55.6333
# 
# $error
# [1] 6.555276e-06
```

Not the same result as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a similar result by doubly integrating the function with a 1-dim. 
integration routine such as `integrate` in Base R.

```
f = function(x) {
    integrate(function(y) {sqrt(1 - (x/5)^2 - (y/8.5)^2)},
              0, 8.5*sqrt(1 - (x/5)^2))$value
}

(res = 2.5 * integrate(Vectorize(f), 0, 5)$value)
## [1] 55.63237
```

Your manual calculation is probably wrong.