# Double integrate in R

Tags: r, integral

I would like to ask if any of you guys can help me find how can I compute a double integral of a given joint distribution e.g. `dnorm(x,m1,s1)*dnorm(y,m2,s2)*CopulaDensity` with `Ymin=-inf`, `Ymax=inf`, and `Xmin= x` and `Xmax = inf`? I want to do this in R.

Thanks a lot .

**Note!** `CopulaDensity` is a numeric vector .

Comment: Isn't it `Ymin= x`, not `Xmin= x`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution inspired in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984362/double-integral-in-r-with-2-variables).
But with no `CopulaDensity`.

```
f <- function(x, m1, s1, m2, s2) {
  dnorm(x, m1, s1) * integrate(function(y, m2, s2) {
    dnorm(y, m2, s2)
  }, x, Inf, m2 = m2, s2 = s2)$value
}

(res <- integrate(Vectorize(f), -Inf, Inf, m1 = 0, s1 = 1, m2 = 0, s2 = 1)$value)
#[1] 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Although I need to multiply those 2 densities with a numeric vector as mentioned above. Any thoughts on how I can embed that  ?

Comment: @Giorgos You can have an extra argument `vec` at the end of `f <- function(x, m1, s1, m2, s2, vec)` and then use it anywhere you want in the function body. If the vector is `v`, put it before the 1st `dnorm`.

Comment: `f <- function(x, m1, s1, m2, s2,v) {
  v*dnorm(x, m1, s1) * integrate(function(y, m2, s2) {
    dnorm(y, m2, s2)
  }, x, Inf, m2 = m2, s2 = s2)$value
}`   Something like this ?

Comment: @Giorgos Yes, for what I understand of the problem that should work. Can you try it with known input/output?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the following error  : `Error in integrate(Vectorize(f), -Inf, Inf, m1 = mean(x), copuladensity = Frank.Density,  : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = function (x, m1, s1, m2, s2, copuladensity)  :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter`

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with the fixed Vector values .